# htaccess URL rewrite is not working in production but works on local

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with URL rewritting and htaccess. I have an URL like `www.example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=name&id=35` but it's too complex for people so I want to change it. I created a directory in my host like `example.com/web/title-for-name/` where I put this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=name&id=35$1 [L,NC]
```

I've tested it in my local and it seems to work but when I test it in production it just redirect me changing my URL. Mod-rewrite is enabled because my web is rewriting other URLs. Also `AllowOverride` is set to `All`. The main difference between my local and production is that I'm not using Varnish.

Comment: This would _append_ any additional URL path onto the end of the substituted URL, as part of the `id` parameter - is that the intention? Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the directive itself that would cause an _external redirect_. The use of Varnish could well be the cause of this.

Comment: Yes, but it could get better. I want to append the GET vars of the Url but it also append the index.html part that it's useless

Comment: If you "want to append the GET vars" then you will need the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag. The URL-path, as matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern notably excludes the query string. (It doesn't look like you need the capturing `$1` backreference?)

Comment: Thanks for the advice w3dk, Changed. Anyway, the main problem it's still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. There was an URL rewrite before mine that changed the domain `.es` to `.com` and changed the rest of my URL so I just changed the link I use to the `.com` domain.

Thanks everyone.